# could not create a list of fields for the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am clicking on REFRESH FIELDS for my query for a shared dataset, and getting this error:

[image]

here's my query:

```
Select
            p.AgeCodePL ,
p.BirthDate ,
p.CommunityIDY  ,
p.Company   ,
p.CreatedbyUser ,
p.DateCreated   ,
p.DateExpired   ,
p.DateUpdated   ,
p.Department    ,
p.EthnicityFK   ,
p.FirstName firstFirstName,
p.GenderUL  ,
p.LastName  ,
p.MaritalStatusUL   ,
p.MiddleName    ,
p.NickName  ,
p.PeopleIDY ,
p.PrefixUL  ,
p.RaceUL    ,
p.ReligionUL    ,
p.Salutation    ,
p.SpouseName    ,
p.SSN   ,
p.SuffixUL  ,
p.Title ,
p.UpdatedbyUser ,
r.ACT_ID    ,
r.HEA_ID    ,
r.INT_ID    ,
r.LIF_ID    ,
r.NetworkSet    ,
r.PER_ID    ,
r.RES_Active    ,
r.RES_Bio   ,
r.RES_BioUpdate ,
r.RES_BioUpdateBy   ,
r.RES_CommunityIDY  ,
r.RES_CurrentUnitNumber ,
r.RES_DateStarted   ,
r.RES_DiscNotes1    ,
r.RES_DiscNotes2    ,
r.RES_DiscNotes3    ,
r.RES_DiscNotes4    ,
r.RES_DiscNotes5    ,
r.RES_ExpiredDate   ,
r.RES_ExpiredUser   ,
r.RES_FinishedDate  ,
r.RES_HasImage  ,
r.RES_LastUserUpdated   ,
r.RES_LobbyBio  ,
r.RES_LobbyBioUpdate    ,
r.RES_LobbyBioUpdateBy  ,
r.RES_NoPart    ,
r.RES_PeopleIDY ,
r.RES_PhyMoveInDate ,
r.RES_TasksSet  ,
r.RES_UpdatedImage  ,
r.STA_ID    ,
r.STA_Type  ,
r.TES_ID    ,
rr.CommunityIDY ,
rr.CurrentUnitNumber    ,
rr.Gender   ,
rr.MainBirthDate    ,
rr.MainFirstName    ,
rr.MainLastName ,
rr.MainPeopleIDY    ,
rr.Name ,
rr.ProspectIDY  ,
s.RES_ID    ,
s.STA_Active    ,
s.STA_CreatedOn ,
s.STA_DateUpdated   ,
s.STA_Details   ,
s.STA_EditedDate    ,
s.STA_EditedUser    ,
s.STA_ID    ,
s.STA_Reason    ,
s.STA_Solution  ,
s.STA_Type  ,
s.STA_User  ,
u.PRO_ID    ,
u.STU_ID    ,
u.TEA_ID    ,
u.USR_AboutMe   ,
u.USR_Active    ,
u.USR_AllComm   ,
u.USR_Bday  ,
u.USR_BdayDay   ,
u.USR_CellPhone ,
u.USR_CommLocation  ,
u.USR_CommunityIDY  ,
u.USR_ContactFor    ,
u.USR_DirectPhone   ,
u.USR_Email ,
u.USR_EntAdmin  ,
u.USR_FavBooks  ,
u.USR_FavMovies ,
u.USR_FavPart   ,
u.USR_FavQuotes ,
u.USR_Fax   ,
u.USR_First ,
u.USR_Goals ,
u.USR_HasImage  ,
u.USR_HomeTown  ,
u.USR_ID    ,
u.USR_Interests ,
u.USR_INTL_Password ,
u.USR_INTL_UserName ,
u.USR_IsSales   ,
u.USR_JoinedKisco   ,
u.USR_Last  ,
u.USR_LastLogin ,
u.USR_LastProUpdate ,
u.USR_Name  ,
u.USR_OtherTeams    ,
u.USR_Password  ,
u.USR_PlacesBeen    ,
u.USR_REPS_Password ,
u.USR_REPS_UserIDY  ,
u.USR_REPS_UserName ,
u.USR_Role  ,
u.USR_RoleDescrip   

            from
            Status s
            Inner Join Residents r
            ON r.RES_ID = s.RES_ID
            Left Join REPSResidents rr
            ON rr.MainPeopleIDY = r.RES_PeopleIDY
            Inner Join Associate u
            ON s.STA_User = u.USR_ID
            Inner Join KSLSQL1.[RPS-201065-000].dbo.people p
            ON r.RES_PeopleIDY = p.PeopleIDY
            Where
            rr.CommunityIDY in (@Community)
            and (s.STA_Reason is not null and s.STA_Reason <> '')
and s.STA_Active = 1
and s.STA_DateUpdated between @BegDate and dateadd(d,1,@EndDate)
Order by
s.STA_DateUpdated DESC
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you just run `Select * from rewSQL1.[RPS-000].dbo.people` do you get an error?

Answer (score 30):

The issue is because you have [two columns with the exact same name](http://arcanecode.com/2010/07/30/ssrs-quick-tip-an-item-with-the-same-key-has-already-been-added/) in your query:

```
r.RES_ID    ,
s.RES_ID    ,
```

The columns must have different names.  Either give them an alias to make them distinct or remove one of them, since they will have identical values based on your join.

Comment: thanks ive updated but still the same issue

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов You have two `CommunityIDY` columns. You cannot have any columns with the same names

Comment: Translation. Write it for me.

Comment: just to add to the list of duplicates: CommunityIDY ,
RES_ID ,
STA_ID ,
STA_Type ,  Pretty sure this is the full list and that all that's needed is to alias 1 of the dups something like R_Res_ID S_RES_ID etc.

Comment: @xQbert This just elaborates on the issue, there are too many columns with the same name.

Comment: @bluefeet Agreed. But it lists all duplicates columns. So I guess I'm missing the point of the follow-up comment.  It wasn't a critique of the response provided, just a comment to "Add to the list of duplicates"  So what am I missing?

Comment: @xQbert Nothing, I was just pointing out that the OP has many columns with duplicated names. :)

Comment: Oo.. fair enough.  I thought I had done something shameful and was about to be chastised by the SO community so I was scouring the FAQ for some rule I had broken. and now I move on to the next question...